# Properties of Object Changed when another Object changed that is the copy of Object in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js

```
const initFromData =
            {
                code: '', // ----------------string
                name: '', // ---------------string
                working_days: [], // ---------------array
                shift_period: [] // ---------------array contains multiple array
            };


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            regForm: Object.assign({}, initFromData)
         }
      }
}
```

Changes of `regForm. shift_period` is also affects `initFromData.shift_period`. But other properties has no issue. Why? How to prevent this?

Comment: try `regForm: {...initFromData}`

Comment: Using `Object.assign()` or the spread syntax above only creates a shallow copy of the object. The problem there is that your array properties will be using the same references

Comment: Using lodash   `_.cloneDeep(initFromData)`    is working properly